# Convert Json without root element to object? using Gson, Ksoap2, Json.NET

Tags: android, json, serialization, gson, ksoap2

In my android application I'm getting this response from my web service:

```
[
{
 "bookNum":1,
 "title":"Halo the fall",
 "author":"Erick Nylum"
},
{
 "bookNum":2,
 "title":"Halo contact",
 "author":"Erick Nylum"
}
]
```

In android I'm trying to use this json to convert in an array or list object, because I don't have a root element

```java
        btnConsumer = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnConsumer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);       
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet=true;       
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);// because AndroidHttpTransport now is d
            try {
                httpTransport.debug = true; // ?
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Object response = (Object) envelope.getResponse();
                lblView.setText(response.toString());

                String jsonData= response.toString();
                JSONObject json= new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONObject data= json.getJSONObject("book");//no root ERROR

            }catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                lblView.setText(e.toString());
                // lblView.setText(e.getMessage());
            }           
        }
    });
```

jsonData is my JSON string, I don't know how to transform to this object.

```java
public class books {
            @SerializedName("bookNum")
                private String BookNum;
                @SerializedName("title")
                private String Title;
                @SerializedName("author")
                private String Author;

                public books() {
                    // contructor vacio
                }

                public books(String bookNum, String title, String author) {
                    super();
                    this.setBookNum(bookNum);
                    this.setTitle(title);
                    this.setAuthor(author);
                }

                public String getBookNum() {
                    return BookNum;
                }

                public String getTitle() {
                    return Title;
                }

                public String getAuthor() {
                    return Author;
                }

                public void setBookNum(String bookNum) {
                    BookNum = bookNum;
                }

                public void setTitle(String title) {
                    Title = title;
                }

                public void setAuthor(String author) {
                    Author = author;
                }

            }
```

My web services

```cs
[WebMethod(Description = "try return a LIST of book object in Json format using Newtonsoft")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ShowAllBooks()
{
    string url = "Server=localhost; database=books; password=system; user=sa;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(url);
    conn.Open();

    MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
    //select
    command.CommandText = ("select * from reading");
    command.Connection = conn;
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    List<Book> listaBooks = new List<Book>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.bookNum = Convert.ToInt16(reader.GetString(0));
        book.title = reader.GetString(1).ToString();
        book.author = reader.GetString(2).ToString();
        listaBooks.Add(book);
    }
    command.Connection.Close();

    //var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    //settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;

    //var typebook = Type.GetType("WS_Basico.Book");
    //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaBooks,Formatting.Indented, settings); 
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listaBooks, Formatting.Indented);

    return json;
}
```

But I can't, all methods that I saw (a lot) use a "root element" normally the object name, In my case I don't have one.
What it's wrong?
I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjzxJIT74UI) but he has a root element in his JSON (the object name).

Somebody please give me tutorial or link or sample code?

---

thanks a lot @Paresh.. you made my day.. With your help I still go ahead .. Actually I create a method that receive the jsonData and put the data in a listView following this [link](http://vicentepalomero.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-anadir-y-eliminar-elementos-de.html) ... is the right way?

```java
protected void ShowInView(String jsonData) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONArray arrayResponse;

    try {
        arrayResponse = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayResponse.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject book = arrayResponse.getJSONObject(i);
            bookArrayList.add(Integer.toString(book.getInt("bookNum"))+" - "+book.getString("title"));
        }
        bookList.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi , Check this link for using gson for array : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: @MohitSharma it's very useful.. now I'm finishing my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue is here:**

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONObject data= json.getJSONObject("book");//no root ERROR
```

**Solution:**
Issue is your are getting `JSONArray` in response but you are creating JSONObject with the response string.

```
JSONArray arrayResponse = new JSONArray(jsonData);  // correct way
```

Now, to get sub JSON objects, you have to iterate through the JSONArray.

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayResponse.length(); i++)
{
   JSONObject subObj = arrrayResponse.getJSONObject(i);
    // Now you can fetch strings/int and other values from object.
}
```

Comment: How about gson..How can we serialize data without root element in Gson when using retrofit

Comment: @GeorgeThomas I didn't get your question! And I think it's a different question than the asked

Comment: can we parse the same response in the question using GSON lib?

Comment: @GeorgeThomas you mean JSON Array? Please be more specific!

Comment: @PareshMayani The response in the question is an array without a root element like above. In GSON we cretate a List<CustomObject> rootElementName; r8 but for the response above we dont have a root element for the array r8. So i was wondering whether we could serialize a array response without a root element using GSON lib