# How to parse a JSON File without root element using org.json.simple?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I want to parse json file "c:/employeesRecord.json" using org.json.simple library. Below is sample json data, each record is sperated by next line in the file.

```
{"Employees ":["A ;B ;C ;D ;E ;F"],"JobTitle":"Software Engineer"}
{"Employees ":["A ;B ;C ;D ;E ;F"],"JobTitle":"Software Engineer"}
{"Employees ":["A ;B ;C ;D ;E ;F"],"JobTitle":"Software Engineer"}
...
```

How to parse such json file without root element using org.json.simple.

Comment: Split your string/buffer by newline (`.split("\n")`) and parse them one by one?

Comment: Would you like to show me an example?

Comment: For Android using Gson it is solved in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334650/convert-json-without-root-element-to-object-using-gson-ksoap2-json-net)

Comment: You are encouraged to post your own solutions as answers to your question.

Comment: Yes my json is not valid but i need to process such files. Thanks  @PEMapModder your solution works for.

Comment: Sorry @PEMapModder I cannot vote your answer. I have no such privileges.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can "tweak" the input from the file and change it into a valid json format

```
String json = <your json from file>
json = "[" + json + "]";
json = json.replace("\n",",");
// parse your json, now it should be a valid.
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the full file is not a valid JSON object you will need to parse it line-by-line, ie. read first line, parse it using your parser, save the result and then repeat for the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Parse it line by line after spliting by `\n`.

```
String[] lines = json.split("\n");
List<JsonObject> objects = new ArrayList<>(lines.length); // depending on the JSON library you are using

for(String line : lines) {
    objects.add(parseJson(line));
}
```