# How to parse a JSON string with no root element?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file like below:

```
{
  "name":"A",
  "age":19
}
{
  "name":"B",
  "age":20
}
```

So basically the file contains a list of people.

I tried to use `json.loads(str_content)` in Python 3, but it returned the error of `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:`.

I checked with an online JSON parser (http://json.parser.online.fr) and it told me the same problem.

How to parse a JSON file without a root element but a list of JSON objects?

Comment: There is a syntax error in `age:20`

Comment: The problem is you *don't* have a JSON file; what's creating that file, could it be modified to have a single root array?

Comment: @Chirag thanks, I modified it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think the file is created from MongoDB. In fact I god a BSON file, then I converted it to JSON.

Comment: Is it stored in multi-line json? Like this `{"name":"A","age":19}
{"name":"B","age":20}` Each in new line

Comment: But it *isn't* JSON. You can synthesize it into a JSON file by adding a pair of square brackets and a comma between elements. Probably `jq -r .` can do this for you automatically, or if the fragments are one line per dict, you can use [a simple `sed` script.](/q/35021524)

Comment: Just read it in groups of 4 lines and pass them to `json.loads()` to get one object at a time.

Comment: @Chirag yes, but each JSON object is stored in multi-lines as well. Otherwise I can parse by lines.

Comment: @martineau each JSON object has a different number of lines (for instance, someone has information of ``weight`` but someone does not)

Comment: Show sample output of *" In fact I god a BSON file"*

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397606/how-to-parse-a-json-file-without-root-element-using-org-json-simple

Comment: not a proper json file

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the string you are trying to parse is not a valid JSON document. It is  actually a concatenation of JSON documents. So the simple `json.loads()` will  not work.

You can use instead something based on https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode . E.g: (code is a bit ugly but the logic should be clear):

```
import json

s = """{
  "name":"A",
  "age":19
}
{
  "name":"B",
  "age":20
}"""

def iter_jsons(s):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()

    i = 0
    while True:
        doc, i2 = decoder.raw_decode(s[i:].strip())
        yield doc
        if i == i2:
            break
        i= i2

print(list(iter_jsons(s)))
```

> > > [{'name': 'A', 'age': 19}, {'name': 'B', 'age': 20}]

Comment: If there are no nested dicts you could simply look for the closing brace and parse up to that point.

Comment: I can't find anything in the json standard that indicates that a JSON document must have a root element.

Comment: @TomasZubiri It is not explicitly stated as text in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2 , but the ABNF indicates that a JSON-text is a SINGLE value

Comment: @TomasZubiri: I believe the standard indicates that a JSON document must either be a single JSON object enclosed in `{`, `}` brackets or a comma delimited list of them enclosed in `[`, `]` brackets. This answer looks like a very clever workaround allowing this non-compliant input to be decoded into the list it should have been in the first place.

Comment: @tripleee: that is correct, but I'd rather not assume anything about the content I am trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm

```
import json        
json_file = "myfile.json"

objects = json.load(open(json_file))

for person in objects:
    name = person['name']
    print(name)
```